# Paypal Sandbox How can we add MYR Currency code?

Tags: php, paypal

[image: How can we add "MYR" currency to our Sandbox Account]

Because i am not seeing the currency MYR (Malaysian currency ) Code. Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an issue for Paypal support.

Answer (score 0):

As paypal said,Malaysian Ringgit (only for members resident in Malaysia)->MYR
This currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency balance for in-country PayPal accounts only.

Check the offical link:
https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_wa-outside